# Multiple column condition check with multiple rows to be found

Tags: sql

```
ID  A   B   c   D   E(Time)
---------------------------
1   J   1   A   B   1
2   J   1   A   S   2
3   M   1   A   B   1
4   M   1   A   B   2
5   M   2   A   S   3
6   M   2   A   S   4
7   T   1   A   B   1
8   T   2   A   S   2
9   T   1   A   B   3
10  k   1   A   B   1
11  k   1   A   B   2
```

I need to find unique values with multiple column with some added condition. The unique value are combination of Col A,B and D.

If Col A has only two rows (like record 1 and 2) and the Column B is same on both data and there is a different value as in Column D , BUT the S are only coming after B we dont want to see those records

If Col A has only multiple rows (like record 3 to 6 ) with different Col B and D, 
whereas in COulmn D S are coming after B we dont want to see those records.

If Col A has only multiple rows (like record 7 to 9 ) with different Col B and D, 
whereas in COulmn D there is a S before B  we want to see those records.

If Col A has only multiple rows (like record 10 to 11 ) with different Col B and same column D we dont  want to see those records.

any input , able to get to see the first and last of it using partition by and using unbounded in query...

Seems like the basic logic to look for is on to See if S preceds any B on Column D then show all those records using the partition...

Desired output is  row 7-9: THis is Based on logic for same column A , we had a Sell before Buy from customer on Column D when order by column E time.

```
ID  A   B   C   D   E(Time)
---------------------------------------------------
7   T   1   A   B   1
8   T   2   A   S   2
9   T   1   A   B   3
```

Comment: err, can you give us your desired output from this?  I, at least, am having a difficult time understanding what it is you want.

Comment: Sure , I want the output from row no rown no 7-9 based on column D as there in column D there is a S before buy for records from row 7- row 9.

Comment: 7 T 1 A B 1<br/> 8 T 2 A S 2<br/> 9 T 1 A B 3

Comment: What on Earth does any of this mean?  There's no sense or comprehensibility to it. Your columns are unlabelled, column D and S/B are undefined as to what these **actually mean**, then there's column E..  **This is a horrible question.**

Comment: apologize if its not clear, B means customer bought something from us,S meanms customer sold something to us....i am looking at data prespective..

Comment: so please edit your question and add your Comments in it **desired output** and better columnnames

Comment: Made changes, please let me know if this is better.

Comment: If all `(A, B, D)` combinations are supposed to be unique, your example contains violations to that rule. Row (4) is a duplicate of (3), as are: (6) of (5), (9) of (7), (11) of (10). Or what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I started to write a query to do this, but ran out of "Spare time", your criteria is very hard to follow, If you comment out the "Where" at the bottom of the query it functions but doesn't yet produce your desired effect.

Possibly this can lead you in a direction to achive your goal ...

```
WITH Src AS (
    SELECT 1 AS ID, 'J' AS A, 1 AS B, 'A' AS C, 'B' AS D, 1 AS E
    UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'J', 1, 'A', 'S', 2
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'M', 1, 'A', 'B', 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'M', 1, 'A', 'B', 2
    UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'M', 2, 'A', 'S', 3
    UNION ALL SELECT 6, 'M', 2, 'A', 'S', 4
    UNION ALL SELECT 7, 'T', 1, 'A', 'B', 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 8, 'T', 2, 'A', 'S', 2
    UNION ALL SELECT 9, 'T', 1, 'A', 'B', 3
    UNION ALL SELECT 10, 'k', 1, 'A', 'B', 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 11, 'k', 1, 'A', 'B', 2
), ACnt AS (
    SELECT A, Count(*) AS Cnt
    FROM Src
    GROUP BY A
), FirstD AS (
    SELECT A, D
    FROM Src
    WHERE E=1
), FirstSRow AS (
    SELECT A, Min(E) AS E
    FROM Src
    WHERE D='S'
    GROUP BY A
), LastBRow AS (
    SELECT A, Max(E) AS E
    FROM Src
    WHERE D='B'
    GROUP BY A
), Mins AS (
    SELECT A, Min(D) AS D, Min(B) AS B
    FROM Src
    GROUP BY A
), Maxs AS (
    SELECT A, Max(D) AS D, Max(B) AS B
    FROM Src
    GROUP BY A
)
SELECT Src.*
FROM Src
    JOIN ACnt ON ACnt.A=Src.A
    JOIN FirstD ON FirstD.A=Src.A
    JOIN Mins ON Mins.A=Src.A
    JOIN Maxs ON Maxs.A=Src.A
    LEFT JOIN FirstSRow ON FirstSRow.A=Src.A
    LEFT JOIN LastBRow ON LastBRow.A=Src.A
WHERE 
    NOT (ACnt.Cnt=2 AND Mins.B=Maxs.B AND Mins.D<>Maxs.D AND FirstSRow.E < LastBRow.E)
    AND NOT (ACnt.Cnt>=3 AND Mins.B<>Maxs.B AND Mins.D<>Maxs.D AND FirstD.D='B')
    AND (ACnt.Cnt>=3 AND Mins.B<>Maxs.B AND Mins.D<>Maxs.D AND FirstD.D='B')
```